# Why use IKernel over IWindsorContainer?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have seen in several code examples where people have used `IKernel` rather than use `IWindsorContainer`.  Why is this?

Here is one example: http://docs.castleproject.org/(S(kwaa14uzdj55gv55dzgf0vui))/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-two-plugging-Windsor-in.ashx

In the above example it came to bite me because I added a subresolver

```
Container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(
        new CollectionResolver(Container.Kernel, true));
```

that will allow me to inject collections... but yet it wasnt working. I figured out that because just the `IKernel` was being used it couldnt use the full features of Windsor.  Why would someone ever want to use the Kernel over the full container?  I think if you are going to implement Windsor, use the full container.  Am I wrong?  Why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are historical reasons for that. Originally Castle project had two containers: MicroKernel (`IKernel`) which provided all the base functionality and extension points, and Windsor `IWindsorContainer` which was a wrapper around MicroKernel providing additional features (like XML configuration, proxies etc) and was wrapping the MicroKernel.

Those were later (in v2.5) merged into a single project/assembly but to avoid breaking existing users the distinction was kept.

Comment: Thanks for the history.  So I would assume going forward if I say I am using Windsor, I dont really need to use IKernal unless I am using something that requires the old IKernel specifically?

Comment: Is it still true that IKernel is automatically registered but IWindsorContainer is not?

Comment: kind of. `IKernel` is available as a dependency OOTB, IWindsorContainer is not, as it is a user facing interface